# Set datagridview rowcount to max 1

Tags: visual-studio-2010, datagridview

Folks I would like to set a datagridview to accept only one row and I'm having a hard time doing that. 
Means after the first row disallow the user to add a new row. 
So the datagridview will always have one row. In Visual Basic though
Any help would greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub Datagridview1_CellBeginEdit(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DatagridviewCellCancelEventArgs) Handles DataGridView.CellBeginEdit

    For Each r As DataGridViewRow in DataGridView1.Rows

   If r.IsNewRow AndAlso DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index = 0
       e.Cancel = False
     Else
     e.Cancel = True
      End If
Next

 End Sub
```